# Pasar ID mediante una función onclick Javascript PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Vengo a pedirles de su apoyo en el problema que se me presentó al realizar un carrito de compras.

Tengo un **Button** el cual debe hacer la función de eliminar un producto, sin embargo no se que esto haciendo mal.

La función de mi **Button** es la siguiente:

```html
<button id="btn-elimina" data-id="<?php echo $_id; ?>" onclick="elimina()">Eliminar del carrito</button>
```

Y lo estoy mandando por una función `fetch`, sin embargo no me hace ninguna acción.

Esta es la función del `fetch`:

```js
function elimina() {

  let botonElimina = document.getElementById('btn-elimina')
  let recipient = botonElimina.value

  let url = 'clases/actualizar_carrito.php';
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('action', 'eliminar');
  formData.append('id', recipient);

  fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      mode: 'cors',
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.ok) {
        location.reload();
      }
    })
}
```

Espero que puedan apoyarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes enviar el **id** como parámetro a la función `elimina()` y así evitas el tener que capturarlo desde alguna propiedad o atributo del botón en `JS`.

```
<button id="btn-elimina" onclick="elimina(<?=$_id?>)">Eliminar del carrito</button>
```

Tu función quedaría así, por ejemplo:

```js
function elimina(id) {

  let recipient = id

  let url = 'clases/actualizar_carrito.php';
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('action', 'eliminar');
  formData.append('id', recipient);

  fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      mode: 'cors',
    }).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      if (data.ok) {
        location.reload();
      }
    })
}
```

```html
<button id="btn-elimina" onclick="elimina(2780)">Eliminar del carrito</button>
```

Comment: Perfecto @DjCrazy, me ha funcionado de maravilla, te agradezco mucho por el apoyo

Comment: Es con todo el gusto!. Te sugiero aceptar la respuesta con el check que hay al lado izquierdo para que sirva de referencia a futuros visitantes y de paso ambos ganamos reputación en la comunidad.